# django extract bool from a list

Tags: python, django

I want to extract a boolean from a list, but I get the error:

> TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

I basically return two values from a function and one of them is a bool but when I want to use it I get the error

```
def validar_cupon(codigo_forma):

    today = date.today()

    if Promos.objects.filter(codigo = codigo_forma, inicia__lte = today, finaliza__gte = today).exists():
        desc = Promos.objects.filter(codigo = codigo_forma, inicia__lte = today, finaliza__gte = today).values_list('descuento', flat=True)
        
        return True, desc[0]
    else:
        return False
```

and to extract I was using the index:

```
vc = validar_cupon(codigo_forma)
vc1 = vc[0]
```

that is why I'm getting the error.

Comment: Your first return statement returns a tuple, while the return statement in your `else` clause returns a boolean. The error happens because of the latter return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your function returns False, sometimes it returns a tuple.  This is not good practice.   You are likely getting an error when False is returned and you are trying to index it.  Without seeing the actual error I am guessing this would fix it...

```
def validar_cupon(codigo_forma):
    today = date.today()
    if Promos.objects.filter(codigo = codigo_forma, inicia__lte = today, finaliza__gte = today).exists():
        desc = Promos.objects.filter(codigo = codigo_forma, inicia__lte = today, finaliza__gte = today).values_list('descuento', flat=True)
        return True, desc[0]
    else:
        return False, None
```

at least this way it always returns a tuple with two items in it.

These edits would also make your code more readable and efficient.

```
def validar_cupon(codigo_forma):
    today = date.today()
    obj = Promos.objects.filter(
        codigo = codigo_forma, inicia__lte = today, finaliza__gte = today
    ).only('descuento').first()
    if obj:
        return True, obj.descuento
    else:
        return False, None
```

Comment: At this point returning the booleans is redundant and unpythonic, since `obj.descuento` will evaluate to `True` and `None` will evaluate to `False` so any using code can validate these in a boolean context

Comment: Yeah, but I'm guessing he also wants the descuento attribute to do something with.  This will at least work with any other code he has already written.  This would probably be best done as a @classmethod on the model itself.  But that perhaps might be to advanced without knowing the OCs skill level.

Comment: They can still do whatever they want with `obj.descuento`. Returning a tuple makes no difference what-so-ever

Comment: I don't disagree, I'm just saying my solution would allow the rest of the code he has written to immediately work without having to make changes.

Comment: thanks for your response, the idea is to validate that the item has a valid promo code, so if it has a valid promo code it will return True and the discount amount, if is not valid it returns False, I'm not sure about if returning null instead of False will work, since, like you said, when a False is returned is not in a tuple and not indexed